# How to speed up page parsing in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

What can I do in case if I load the page in Selenium and then I have to do like 100 different parsing requests to this page?
At this moment I use different `driver.findElement(By...)` and the problem is that every time it is a `http (get/post)` request from java into selenium. From this case one simple page parsing costs me like 30+ seconds (too much).
I think that I must get source code (`driver.getPageSource()`) from first request and then parse this string locally (my page does not change while I parse it).

- Can I build some kind of HTML object from this string to keep working with WebElement requests?
- Do I have to use another lib to build HTML object? (for example - jsoup) In this case I will have to rebuild my parsing requests from webelement's and XPath.
- Anything else?

Comment: if the purpose is only to check that the div is there, write a validation javacsript and have it run on the page, returning true/false as required.

Comment: maybe `@CacheLookup` can help you? http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/CacheLookup.html

Comment: My purpose is to do 15 iterations and search for about 10 element values each time. So every time it is 1. `element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."))` 2. `return element.getAttribute("...")` = 1+1 http request to selenium. 2*10*15 = 300 http requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `findElement`, there is no need for Selenium to parse the page to find the element. The parsing of the HTML happens when the page is loaded. Some further parsing may happen due to JavaScript modifications to the page (like when doing `element.innerHTML += ...`). What Selenium does is query the DOM with methods like `.getElementsByClassName`, `.querySelector`, etc. This being said, if your browser is loaded on a remote machine, things can slow down. Even locally, if you are doing a huge amount of round-trip to between your Selenium script and the browser, it can impact the script's speed quite a bit. What can you do?

What I prefer to do when I have a lot of queries to do on a page is to use `.executeScript` to do the work on the browser side. This can reduce dozens of queries to a single one. For instance:

```
List<WebElement> elements = (List<WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
  .executeScript(
    "var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');" + 
    "return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function (el) {" + 
    "  return el.attributes.whatever.value === 'something';" +
    "});");
```

(I've not run the code above. Watch out for typos!)

In this example, you'd get a list of all elements of class `foo` that have an attribute named `whatever` which has a value equal to `something`. (The `Array.prototype.filter.call` rigmarole is because `.getElementsByClassName` returns something that behaves like an `Array` but which is not an `Array` so it does not have a `.filter` method.)

Parsing locally is an option if you know that the page won't change as you examine it. You should get the page's source by using something like:

```
String html = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "return document.documentElement.outerHTML");
```

By doing this, you see the page exactly in the way the browser interpreted it. You will have to use something else than Selenium to parse the HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What should I use if I decide to parse it locally? It would be good if it supports xpath so I could use my old xpath queries from webelement.

Comment: I cannot suggest a library because it's been ages since I've used Java substantially.

Comment: @Louis you should, definitely should start writing books (if not already started) :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try evaluating your elements only when you try to use them?
I dont know about the Java equivalent, but in C# you could do something similar to the following, which would only look for the element when it is used:

```
private static readonly By UsernameSelector = By.Name("username");

private IWebElement UsernameInputElement
{
    get { return Driver.FindElement(UsernameSelector); }
}
```

Comment: A am getting element value at once to save it later into db. I took Jsoup and reworked my xpath requests to jsoup's selectors. It turned out that they are even better than xpath (for me). I got rid of my first '30 sec' parsing and now it goes immediately as it supposed to be.